# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when attempting to assign array from list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, registry

I am attempting to create a two-dimensional array that holds in string form a registry's root key and it's subkeys, so I wanted the array to be

```
string[rootkeys][subkeys]
```

but for some reason when it comes to assigning I get a `NullReferenceException`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my code. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
    public string[][] getAllRootSubKeys(){
        int i = 0;
        int h = 0;
        var allRoots = new List<RegistryKey> {Registry.ClassesRoot, Registry.CurrentUser, Registry.LocalMachine, Registry.Users, Registry.CurrentConfig};

        string[][] rootAndKey = null;

        foreach (var root in allRoots) {
            rootAndKey[i][h] = root.GetSubKeyNames()[h];
            h++;
            if (h == root.SubKeyCount) {
                i++;
                h = 0;
            }
        }
        return rootAndKey;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize `rootAndKey` before trying to assign elements to it. Your looping logic also looks a little funny to me. I'm guessing you'll need something like:

```
string[][] rootAndKey = new string[allRoots.Count][];

for(var i = 0; i < allRoots.Count; i++)
{
    var subkeys = root.GetSubKeyNames();
    rootAndKey[i] = new string[subkeys.Length];
    for(var h = 0; h < subkeys.Length; h++)
    {
        rootAndKey[i][h] = subkeys[h];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Servy - Was working on some example code. Included it there.

Comment: I tried initializing like this: string[][] rootAndKey = new string[allRoots.Count][]; but I got the same exception because as Servy said I need to initialize all the elements of the array...? But I am not sure how I will work that in as I need the array to have the ability to take as many as there are subkeys(Which is not always going to be the same amount.)

Comment: @JBeck - I provided a full code sample that involves initializing both parts of the array.

Comment: Alright great! I used the code as you suggested! Exactly what I needed thank you!